# Unable to post Javascript array via jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am extremely reluctant to ask this question as I know it is something really stupid I am missing, but I simply cannot get this to work. Code below:

```
<script>

var formArray = new Array();
formArray['start'] = "one";
formArray['stopat'] = "two";
formArray['stop_at'] = "three";

$('#my_button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scheduler.php",
        data: formArray,
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Server side PHP Script `scheduler.php`

```
<?php

    print_r($_POST);

?>
```

All I get back logged to the console is an empty array:

```
Array
(
)
```

If I console.log `formArray` within the click function it shows the complete array just fine. So why is it not posting it to my PHP file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did a console log as the first line with the click function, it prints the array just fine. it shows `[start: "one", stopat: "two", stop_at: "three"]`

Comment: If using Firebug, Chrome developer tools etc, you can click on network/net tab and see the Headers and Response, these can help you see on which side the issue may lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `Array()` to `Object()` would work as well.

You would get:

```
Array
(
    [start] => one
    [stopat] => two
    [stop_at] => three
)
```

Comment: We have a winner... `new Object()` rather than `new Array()` has fixed the issue. The server is now returning the array that was posted. Can anyone advise as to what exactly the problem is with using an array rather than an object?

Comment: @superphonic I think it is because Object creates a json.

Comment: Instead of `new Object`, is should be `{}`. Also, arrays are **arrays**, and their indices are numeric. When they get serialize to JSON, their indices get iterated over, not their properties.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding **string properties** to an array, which is for storing numeric indices.

Use an object instead:

```
var formArray = {};
formArray['start'] = "one";
formArray['stopat'] = "two";
formArray['stop_at'] = "three";
```

jQuery will iterate over the indices in an array, using a `for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; ++i)` loop, which will completely miss any properties you've added to the array.

Also, `new Array` should have been `[]` (as `{}` should be preferred over `new Object`). Don't use the `new X` method of initialization for built-in types. (Crockford, The Good Parts)

Comment: Ah... Thanks for the explanation. This makes sense now. I have already accepted the other answer regarding using an object, but I really appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Arrays are designed to hold an ordered sequence of items with integer keys. When jQuery converts a data structure into Form URL Encoded data and encounters an array, it will iterate over those integer keys and not over named keys.

**Use an Object if you want to have named keys**.

Change `new Array()` to `newObject()`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Ajax like this and see if it works: `data: {data: formArray}, dataType: 'JSON'`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scheduler.php",
        data: {data : formArray},
        dataType: 'JSON'
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);

        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
print_r($_POST['data']);
```